# Monitor significant battery changes in Android 8.0 and up?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, batterylevel

The [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#MonitorLevel) is pretty straight forward on how to subscribe `BroadcastReceiver`s to listen for when the battery is running low.

However, Android 8.0 has practically axed implicit broadcasts as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts). The `android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW` intent filter, which is the one I'm interested in for this scenario, is not one of the [few exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) listed. So, if I need the app to perform some action when the battery is running low, can I not do this any more starting in Android 8.0?

Comment: If your process is already running, you can listen for that broadcast via `registerReceiver()`. If your intention was to do something when the battery gets low even if your app is not running... then I suspect that you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The comment above is correct. Once you target 26 there's no way to listen for any power related changes. You'd need to do something like wake up periodically and poll for the data. Since battery levels do not change quickly it seems you could do this relatively infrequently and still get a reasonable user experience without killing the battery (as long as you follow best practices for that as well).

Unfortunately, this page:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring which you'd hope would be the bible for this sort of thing isn't up to date with the API 26 changes you noted.